# How to split the last column into multiple columns, but keep the old as a whole in python

Tags: python, pandas, split

While it is easy to split a column, but how can I keep the splited column?

E.g.

```
a;b;c;d;e;f;g
a;b;c;d;e;f;g
a;b;c;d;e;f;g
a;b;c;d;e;f;g
```

now split g in to h,i,j,k, but keep g as g ( g -> h,i,j,k)

```
a;b;c;d;e;f;g;h;i;j;k
a;b;c;d;e;f;g;h;i;j;k
a;b;c;d;e;f;g;h;i;j;k
a;b;c;d;e;f;g;h;i;j;k
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
df[['h','i','j','k']] = df['g'].str.split(',', expand=True)
```

Or:

```
df1 = df['g'].str.split(',', expand=True)
df1.columns = ['h','i','j','k'] 
df = pd.concat([df, df1], axis=1)
```

Comment: How is it possible, if I have no columns, but only lines of strings. Is it also possible without pandas?

Comment: I am not sure if understand - need create from column `g` another columns with some separator? Because with your sample it is a bit unclear. Can you explain more?